# Why different behaviors for OOME while trying to catch it?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I need some understanding from you experts

This Program does not go to catch block(as Heap is full, but I want to understand why)

```
public class OOME_NotCatch {

    static List l = new ArrayList();
    static Long i = new Long(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                l.add(i);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Encountered OutOfMemoryError");
        }
    }
}
//Console : Exception in thread "main"
```

But the below Program runs good, even after getting OOME:

```
public class Catch_OOME_Collection {

    static List l = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                l.add(new byte[1000000]);
                System.out.println("size " + l.size());
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println("Encountered OutOfMemoryError");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("size of list is  " + l.size());
            Iterator i = l.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(i.next().toString());
                i.remove();
            }
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("keep printing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am bit confused, after seeing different results for the same error OOME. Please guide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding is that, in the first program, the OOME is thrown when trying to allocate a new Long object, which takes only a few bytes of memory. This means that the heap is completely full, and that no memory is available anymore to run the catch block.

In the second program, the OOME is thrown when trying to allocate a new array of 1 million bytes. It fails, but that can mean that the heap still has 999,990 bytes available, which is enough to let the catch block execute.

Comment: I don't understand the analysis of the first program. Besides that the exception handler runs for me, how would the JVM be able to start up in a state that wouldn't allow it to allocate essentially any memory at all? I'd find it more likely that the JVM is shutting down before sysout flushes, and using syserr might produce a different result for the OP.

Comment: The JVM needs to allocate memory to execute the instructions in the catch block, (print the stack trace, etc.) and doesn't have any. So the JVM exits. In short, my answer is similar to Joni's answer, but more focused on why the second program leaves the JVM with available memory whereas the first one does not.

Comment: Okay, but what does that have to do with allocating a new `Long`?

Comment: The first loop does `i++` in a loop, where `i` is a Long. That allocates a new Long at each iteration. So it probably fails when trying to allocate this new Long. Which means that the JVM doesn't even have enough memory available to allocate something like 24 bytes.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that'd create a new Long, duh; never mind. Except that I still bet it's pretty implementation and/or timing-dependent regarding seeing sysout output in the handler.

Answer (score 5):

Both programs enter the catch block. What happens is that either of them can run out of memory again before it manages to generate and print a message, and the program receives a new `OutOfMemoryError` right away.

When I try the first program I do see the output that the catch block generates, which goes to show how unpredictable program execution is once an error is thrown. In the stack trace I see that the OOME was thrown while trying to create a new backing array for the `ArrayList`, which means there still was enough memory to run the catch block. If the OOME was thrown while creating the smaller `Long` object things might be different.

What's important to note is that you can't really catch an `OutOfMemoryError` in a meaningful way: the error can be thrown in a very inconvenient place, leaving internal data structures in inconsistent states. In this case there are no visible ill-effects, but if you investigated the internal fields of the `ArrayList` you would find that its `modCount` field has been incremented without the list actually having been modified.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. When the Exception is caught, it doesn't even have enough memory to print?

Comment: The method `e.printStackTrace()` may have to create many strings and other objects to print the message. When the program is running with little memory creating even one extra object may cause another OOME.

Comment: So when this Exception is thrown, what can the program actually do?

Comment: The program can handle the exception without allocating new memory and then exit. When an internal error like OOME is thrown the program state can be completely unpredictable and it's impractical to try to do anything else.

Comment: Print predefined (i.e. compile-time constant) messages. Flush buffers, and close files.  If you're lucky, terminate running child processes.  This is about all you can usefully do in response to an OOME.

Answer (score 0):

The first program runs out of memory when either allocating a `Long` or more probably increasing the size of the internal array.

The second program almost certainly runs out of memory when allocating a `byte[1000000].` This is probably a much larger amount of memory than the cause of the failure of the first program, so the existing memory is probably nowhere near as exhausted as in the first case, so the code in the `catch` block can succeed in allocating a few `Strings` etc to do what it has to do.